# How to add background image on a table oracle procedure

Tags: html, oracle, stored-procedures, html-email

I'm trying to add a background image on my table in oracle. Here is my code.  When the email is sent the image does not show in the background of the table.  This is stored in a procedure.

```
<table width="100%" style="background:url(http://linktomyimage.png);  background-repeat:no-repeat;">
   <tr>

for i in (select doc, source, title from table)
loop
    msg_html := msg_html ||'<td>'||'i.doc||'</td><td>'||'i.source||'</td><td>'||'i.title||'</td>
end loop;
    msg_html := msg_html ||'</tr></table>';
```

Comment: I see an arror in your html: `</td>td>`

Comment: First, examine the final generated email source for html errors and correct them. Second, note that the handling of background images is inconsistent across many email clients - especially outlook: http://blog.mailermailer.com/email-design/background-images-in-html-email-the-naked-truth

Comment: It's weird because it works in a td just fine but when i place it in the table it doesn't

Comment: fixed the <td> and still not working.

Comment: What you've shown has single-quote issues inside the loop, and a missing double-quote at the end of the style string. Can you show the actual code you're using to generate the whole thing, and preferably the generated HTML as it appears in the email you receive.

Comment: That works just fine using the single quotes in the loops, the data returns, it is the background image that's not showing up. The background image is not part of the loop.  I just want to see a background image in the email, if I place it in a <td> then it is only showing in a cell not the background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know there are some validation issues, but I think the issue is that background images are inconsistently supported across email clients. http://www.campaignmoniter.com/css

Now, there IS a way to get it so the majority of email clients will accept this, but it requires quite a bit of code and can become complex.

The  background must be declared in HTML attribute ("background=") and in CSS(background-image:url(htp://). It also needs to be done in VBA for Outlook.

Great place to get started with these is: https://backgrounds.cm/

They do most of the basic work for you with setting up background images and fallback colors, etc.

Example:

```
<td background="https://i.imgur.com/YJOX1PC.png" bgcolor="#7bceeb" width="120" height="92" valign="top" style="background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/YJOX1PC.png); background-color:#7bceeb;" >
  <!--[if gte mso 9]>
  <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="width:120px;height:92px;">
    <v:fill type="tile" src="https://i.imgur.com/YJOX1PC.png" color="#7bceeb" />
    <v:textbox inset="0,0,0,0">
  <![endif]-->
  <div>
   INSERT CONTENT HERE
  </div>
  <!--[if gte mso 9]>
    </v:textbox>
  </v:rect>
  <![endif]-->
</td>
```

Based off the code you provided:

```
 <td background="https://i.imgur.com/YJOX1PC.png" bgcolor="#7bceeb" width="120" height="92" valign="top" style="background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/YJOX1PC.png); background-color:#7bceeb;" >
  <!--[if gte mso 9]>
  <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="width:120px;height:92px;">
    <v:fill type="tile" src="https://i.imgur.com/YJOX1PC.png" color="#7bceeb" />
    <v:textbox inset="0,0,0,0">
  <![endif]-->
  <div>
        msg_html := msg_html || '<table width="100%">
                          <tr>
                            <td nowrap style="font-weight: bold;">Document</td>
                            <th nowrap style="font-weight: bold; text-align:left;">Collections</td>
                            <th nowrap style="font-weight: bold; text-align:left;">Title</td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr style="background-color: #ffffff;">';
for i in (select DOCNO, SOURCE, TITLE, GUIDE from tablename)
loop
        msg_html := msg_html || '<td nowrap class="leftAlignment"><a href="http://mywebsite.com?guideURL='''||i.guide||'''&docnum='''||i.docno||'''">DocNum</a></td>
        <td nowrap class="leftAlignment">'||i.source|| '</td>
        <td nowrap class="leftAlignment">'||i.title|| '</td>
        <td nowrap class="leftAlignment">'||i.source||'</td>
        <td class="leftAlignment"></td></tr><tr class="read">';
 end loop;

 msg_html :=msg_html ||'<td class="leftAlignment"></td></tr>

  <!--[if gte mso 9]>
    </v:textbox>
  </v:rect>
  <![endif]-->
   </div>
   </table>
</td>
```

It looks like the issue is that you forgot to close the table tag in your script and the div tag that holds the script.  If you close those, it should work I believe.